# Java Generics - implements and extends

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to write something like

```
public class A implements B<T implements C> {}
```

and

```
public abstract class M<I extends P> extends R<I extends P> implements Q<I extends P> {}
```

but I am getting errors like Multiple markers and syntax error on token extends, expected. Please let me know what is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 13):

When you have interfaces in generics, you still have to use the `extends` keyword.

In your case, if you know what `T` will be :

```
public class A<T extends C> implements B<T> {}
```

If you don't and you simply have to implements `B` with a `C` type :

```
public class A implements B<C> {}
```

For the second part, once you've defined `I` you can use it as is in your other generic types :

```
public abstract class M<I extends P> extends R<I> implements Q<I> {}
```

---

#### Resources :

- [www.angelikalanger.com - Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)
- [Oracle.com - generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no `implements` keyword in generic bounds. It's only `extends`

Furthermore - you should specify the type parameter only in the class definition, and not in supertypes. I.e.

```
public class A<T extends C> implements B<T> {}
```