# Generic Comparable gets a compiler error

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I have this code:

```
private class Tree<T implements Comparable<T>> {
}
```

I expect to put String objects into this tree, and String implements Comparable, so this looked good at first glance.

But I'm getting the error:

```
> expected
private class Tree<T implements Comparable<?>> {
                    ^
```

Suggestions?

Comment: `T extends Comparable`...

Comment: Can whoever filed a close vote explain it?  This does seem to be about programming to me.  :)

Comment: @Reimeus: asked this one below, but why extends instead of implements?  I expect this to hold types like String, which implement Comparable, but don't subclass it.

Comment: You might want to read this: [Java Generics - implements and extends](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3985225)

Comment: Tom, that link is what I was after; marking this a duplicate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
private class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
}
```

Comment: `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Comment: @apgp88: why extends instead of implements?  I expect the type to be String, which implements Comparable (but doesn't extend it).

Comment: Luiggi, I don't expect to subclass Comparable here; I'm just planning to put normal Strings into it for now.  My understanding is the generic wildcards would only help if I subclassed?

Comment: @DeanJ There is no determination between classes or interfaces in generic types. `extends` is the only keyword which is used here for both, classes and interfaces. This might help: [Java Generics - implements and extends](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3985225)